# htaccess infinite loop after adding trailing slash and redirect 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem with my htaccess. I want to add a trailing slash to my URL. I'm currently developing locally. So here's the htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteBase 
RewriteBase /balade-gourmande

DirectoryIndex index.php

# Add ending slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 


# Main pages
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$                $2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$                 $1.php [L]
```

As you can see, I have a lot of other website on my localhost (Why I have a rewritebase). All my .php files are in the "balade-gourmande" directory.
I have a index.php and a yes.php file in the balade-gourmande folder.

If I try:

localhost/balade-gourmande/ -> It's ok, I land on index.php

localhost/balade-gourmande/yes -> It's ok, I land on yes.php

localhost/balade-gourmande/yes/ -> It's ok, I land on yes.php

The problem is if I enter something wrong, ex: 
localhost/balade-gourmande/whatever
It give me a: localhost/balade-gourmande/whatever.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php/
with infinite loop error...

Can someone help me with this, if you need more info, I'll try m y best.

Thx!

** Edit:
Here's the htaccess located in the root, not in my "balade-gourmande/":

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteBase 

DirectoryIndex index.php

# Error
ErrorDocument 404 '/errorhandler.php'

# Add ending slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 


# Page principales
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your 2 rules below `# Main pages` section with this one:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /balade-gourmande/errorhandler.php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Add ending slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.*?[^/][\s?]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: This is fully working rule from my live website. Make sure it is placed in root .htaccess not inside a sub directory.

Comment: Hello anubhava, Ok, if you're on a live website, but as I said, it's on my local machine I want it to work..

Comment: It has nothing to do with live site or localhost. Rule works same. On your localhost place above rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` file.

Comment: :)
It seems to work. 1 last thing, if I put this htacccess in my localhost folder (root of the server), did i need to remove the htaccess in the "balade-gourmande" folder? 

*** Edit: And if I want to throw a "ErrorDocument 404" line, how I have to write it?
And what happen to the "rewritebase /balade-gourmande"? Did i must write "rewritebase /" instead?

Thx for your help!

Comment: Do you have more rules inside `/balade-gourmande/.htaccess`? If yes then edit the question and paste it. If not then you can rename that `/balade-gourmande/.htaccess` to something else. You don't need `RewriteBase /` line that is optional but having it won't cause harm. You can include any `ErrorDocument 404` line also here.

Comment: So, I've disable the `balade-gourmande/.htaccess`. I tried to put an `ErrorDocument 404` in the root `.htaccess` as you can see in the edit I just made. It redirect to `localhost/errorhandler.php/` instead of `localhost/balade-gourmande/errorhandler.php`. Also, it seem that when I have more than 1 slash `balade-gourmande/portfolio/whatever/yes` it trigger the errorhandler, instead of redirecting to `balade-gourmande/yes.php` THX

Comment: see updated answer with your full .htaccess (to be placed in root)

Comment: Ok, it's working (for what's it's suppose to do) but I think my problem is that I want to make 1 htaccess for all my local site (I can't do that cause the errorHandler need to point in a specific file so I'll need the change it manually every time I switch website) I also have a couple of specific things to change in different .htaccess (products pages, portfolio, etc) so I'll try something else! Thx for your help anubhava!

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to post a new question anytime here on SO if you run into issues and I will try my level best to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

htaccess

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Start rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # Make sure directory listing is disabled
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]



</IfModule>
```

Hope it help you, i never had an error with it